# XSD 1.0 regex to not match two specific hexadecimal strings

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I've been trying to come up with a regex in an XML Schema to match a hex string in the range of `000001-FFFFFE`. I can get either `000000` or `FFFFFF` to not match, but not both within one expression.

**Strings that should match:** `EFEFEF`, `EEEEEF`, `FFFFFE`, `101010`, `10000`, `000001`

**Strings that shouldn't match:** `000000`, `FFFFFF`

Anyone have any ideas? I've been beating my head against my keyboard for a few days over this.

In short, **all 6-digit hexadecimal values *except* `000000` and `FFFFFF` should be allowed.**

Comment: Nope, strict 6 digits. I know basic regex, but the XSD variant has limitations that are throwing me off.

Comment: Yes, my testing environment is a bit..slow. I edited in excitement but the last build just failed. Whoops.

Comment: Did you find the [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47359077/290085) below to work for you?

Comment: I believe it did, but our implementation of verification using XSD turned out to be a bit more complex than I originally assumed. Turns out we cannot process multiple pattern inputs for the time being. Thank you for the help, I'm going to try to change a bit of our architecture to allow this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following XSD, requiring only XSD 1.0,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:simpleType name="OneHexDigitNot0">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern            value="[1-9A-F][0-9A-F]{5}"/>
      <xs:pattern value="[0-9A-F]{1}[1-9A-F][0-9A-F]{4}"/>
      <xs:pattern value="[0-9A-F]{2}[1-9A-F][0-9A-F]{3}"/>
      <xs:pattern value="[0-9A-F]{3}[1-9A-F][0-9A-F]{2}"/>
      <xs:pattern value="[0-9A-F]{4}[1-9A-F][0-9A-F]{1}"/>
      <xs:pattern value="[0-9A-F]{5}[1-9A-F]"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="OneHexDigitNot0AndOneHexDigitNotF">
    <xs:restriction base="OneHexDigitNot0">
      <xs:pattern            value="[0-9A-E][0-9A-F]{5}"/>
      <xs:pattern value="[0-9A-F]{1}[0-9A-E][0-9A-F]{4}"/>
      <xs:pattern value="[0-9A-F]{2}[0-9A-E][0-9A-F]{3}"/>
      <xs:pattern value="[0-9A-F]{3}[0-9A-E][0-9A-F]{2}"/>
      <xs:pattern value="[0-9A-F]{4}[0-9A-E][0-9A-F]{1}"/>
      <xs:pattern value="[0-9A-F]{5}[0-9A-E]"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:element name="r" type="OneHexDigitNot0AndOneHexDigitNotF"/>
</xs:schema>
```

will successfully validate XML documents with an `r` root element and 6-digit hexadecimal content, **except** 000000 and FFFFFF, as requested.